# How to modify UIMenu before it's shown to support dynamic actions

Tags: ios, uikit, ios14, uimenu

iOS 14 adds the ability to display menus upon tapping or long pressing a UIBarButtonItem or UIButton, like so:

```
let menu = UIMenu(children: [UIAction(title: "Action", image: nil) { action in
    //do something
}])
button.menu = menu
barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Show Menu", image: nil, primaryAction: nil, menu: menu)
```

This most often replaces action sheets (`UIAlertController` with `actionSheet` style). It's really common to have a dynamic action sheet where actions are only included or may be disabled based on some state at the time the user taps the button. But with this API, the menu is created at the time the button is created. How can you modify the menu prior to it being presented or otherwise make it dynamic to ensure the appropriate actions are available and in the proper state when it will appear?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can store a reference to your bar button item or button and recreate the menu each time any state changes that affects the available actions in the menu. `menu` is a settable property so it can be changed any time after the button is created. You can also get the current menu and replace its children like so: `button.menu = button.menu?.replacingChildren([])`

For scenarios where you are not informed when the state changes for example, you really need to be able to update the menu right before it appears. There is a `UIDeferredMenuElement` API which allows the action(s) to be generated dynamically. It's a block where you call a completion handler providing an array of `UIMenuElement`. A placeholder with loading UI is added by the system and is replaced once you call the completion handler, so it supports asynchronous determination of menu items. However, this block is only called once and then it is cached and reused so this doesn't do what we need for this scenario. iOS 15 added a new [uncached provider API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uideferredmenuelement/3857602-uncached) which behaves the same way except the block is invoked every time the element is displayed, which is exactly what we need for this scenario.

```
barButtonItem.menu = UIMenu(children: [
    UIDeferredMenuElement.uncached { [weak self] completion in
        var actions = [UIMenuElement]()
        if self?.includeTestAction == true {
            actions.append(UIAction(title: "Test Action") { [weak self] action in
                self?.performTestAction()
            })
        }
        completion(actions)
    }
])
```

Before this API existed, I did find for `UIButton` you can change the menu when the user touches down via target/action like so: `button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTouchedDown(_:)), for: .touchDown)`. This worked only if `showsMenuAsPrimaryAction` was false so they had to long press to open the menu. I didn't find a solution for `UIBarButtonItem`, but you could use a `UIButton` as a custom view.

Comment: Yes. There is no solution for `UIBarButtonItem`. I do not find a way, to detect `UIBarButtonItem` press, then build the menu dynamically and show the dynamic menu.

Comment: everyone is copying and pasting this block with no one have tried it actually

Answer (score 5):

After some trial, I've found out that you can modify the `UIButton` 's `.menu` by setting the `menu` property to `null` first then set the new `UIIMenu`

here is the sample code that I made

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

func generateMenu(max: Int, isRandom: Bool = false) -> UIMenu {
    let n = isRandom ? Int.random(in: 1...max) : max
    print("GENERATED MENU: \(n)")
    let items = (0..<n).compactMap { i -> UIAction in
        UIAction(
            title: "Menu \(i)",
            image: nil
        ) {[weak self] _ in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            self.button.menu = nil // HERE

            self.button.menu = self.generateMenu(max: 10, isRandom: true)
            print("Tap")
        }
    }
 
    let m = UIMenu(
        title: "Test", image: nil,
        identifier: UIMenu.Identifier(rawValue: "Hello.menu"),
        options: .displayInline, children: items)
    return m
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    button.menu = generateMenu(max: 10)
    button.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution for the case with `UIBarButtonItem`. My solution is based on **Jordan H** solution, but I am facing a bug - my menu update method `regenerateContextMenu()` was not called every time on menu appears, and I was getting irrelevant data in the menu. So I changed the code a bit:

```
private lazy var threePointBttn: UIButton = {
    $0.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "ellipsis"), for: .normal)
    // pay attention on UIControl.Event in next line
    $0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(regenerateContextMenu), for: .menuActionTriggered)
    $0.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
    return $0
}(UIButton(type: .system))


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    threePointBttn.menu = createContextMenu()
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: threePointBttn)
}

private func createContextMenu() -> UIMenu {
    let action1 = UIAction(title:...
    // ...
    return UIMenu(title: "Some title", children: [action1, action2...])
}

@objc private func regenerateContextMenu() {
    threePointBttn.menu = createContextMenu()
}
```

tested on iOS 14.7.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding extension for UIMenu:

```
extension UIMenu {
    /// rebuilds menu on every access
    static func lazyMenu(builder: @escaping () -> UIMenu) -> UIMenu {
        return UIMenu(children: [
                UIDeferredMenuElement.uncached { completion in
                    let menu = builder()
                    completion([menu])
                }
            ])
    }
}
```

Then everwhere dynamic menu is needed use:

```
UIMenu.lazyMenu {
    // will be called on every menu access
    return UIMenu(options: .displayInline, children: myDynamicMenuItems)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Modified [Jordan H's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62971661/1806287) version to separate the assignment and build action

This will build the menu on the fly every time the button is tapped

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.menu = UIMenu(children: [
    // build menu every time the button is tapped
            UIDeferredMenuElement.uncached { [weak self] completion in
                if let menu = self?.buildMenu() as? UIMenu {
                completion([menu])
                }
            }
        ])
}

func buildMenu() -> UIMenu {
    var actions: [UIMenuElement] = []
    // build actions
    UIAction(title: "Filter", image: UIImage(systemName: "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle")) { _ in
                self.filterTapped()
    }
    actions.append(filterAction)
    return UIMenu(options: .displayInline, children: actions)
}
```

Comment: everyone is copying and pasting this block with no one have tried it actually