# How to change the state for an UIAction inside UIMenu at runtime?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

How to change the state for an UIAction? The goal is to toggle a state checkmark next to an UIAction inside UIMenu.

[image]

Changing a UIAction's `state` via a reference stored in the view controller does not seem to change the state at all. Am I missing anything?

```
// View Controller
internal var menuAction: UIAction!

private func generatePullDownMenu() -> UIMenu {
    menuAction = UIAction(
        title: "Foo",
        image: UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down"),
        identifier: UIAction.Identifier("come.sample.action"),
        state:  .on
    ) { _ in self.menuAction.state = .off } // <--- THIS LINE


    let menu = UIMenu(
        title: "Sample Menu",
        image: nil,
        identifier: UIMenu.Identifier("com.sample.menu"),
        options: [],
        children: [menuAction]
    )

    return menu
}

// Inside UI setup code block
let buttonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
    title: "",
    image: UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down"),
    primaryAction: nil,
    menu: generatePullDownMenu()
)
```

Tried to change the `action` state from the closure directly and got the "Action is immutable because it is a child of a menu" error. Now I suspect an action object is always an immutable object.

```
menuAction = UIAction(
    title: "Foo",
    image: UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down"),
    identifier: UIAction.Identifier("come.sample.action"),
    state:  .on
) { action in action.state = .off } // <--- THIS LINE
```

Comment: Guys, I am trying to build that exact menu in SwiftUI and I probably have to use UIViewRepresentable to build it in UIKit.
Any idea on how to have both Sort rule (like Date, Size, Kind) with a checkmark in front of the selected rule AND also a chevron up/down on the right side of the selected Soft rule (ONLY in front of this rule) to indicate if the Sort order is either forward of reverse?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Replace the entire `UIMenu` object on state change would do the trick.

```
// view controller
internal var barButton: UIBarButtonItem!

// UI setup function
barButton = UIBarButtonItem(
    image: UIImage(systemName: "arrow.up.arrow.down.square"),
    primaryAction: nil,
    menu: generatePullDownMenu()
)

// On state change inside UIAction 
let actionNextSeen = UIAction(
    title: "foo",
    image: UIImage(systemName: "hourglass", )
    state: someVariable ? .off : .on
) { _ in
    someVariable = false
    self.barButton.menu = self.generatePullDownMenu()
}
```

**REFERENCE**

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653862

Comment: That's basically exactly what I said. The data is used as an intermediary and you re-form the entire menu for next time.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to recreate the Menu. This example will also correctly select the item that was tapped on:

```
private func setupViews()
    timeFrameButton = UIBarButtonItem(
        image: UIImage(systemName: "calendar"),
        menu: createMenu()
    )
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = timeFrameButton
}

private func createMenu(actionTitle: String? = nil) -> UIMenu {
    let menu = UIMenu(title: "Menu", children: [
        UIAction(title: "Yesterday") { [unowned self] action in
            self.timeFrameButton.menu = createMenu(actionTitle: action.title)
        },
        UIAction(title: "Last week") { [unowned self] action in
            self.timeFrameButton.menu = createMenu(actionTitle: action.title)
        },
        UIAction(title: "Last month") { [unowned self] action in
            self.timeFrameButton.menu = createMenu(actionTitle: action.title)
        }
    ])
    
    if let actionTitle = actionTitle {
        menu.children.forEach { action in
            guard let action = action as? UIAction else {
                return
            }
            if action.title == actionTitle {
                action.state = .on
            }
        }
    } else {
        let action = menu.children.first as? UIAction
        action?.state = .on
    }
    
    return menu
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When using iOS 15 or newer, you can use `UIDeferredMenuElement.uncached` to create dynamic `UIAction` objects:

```
let menu = UIMenu(options: .displayInline, children: [
    UIDeferredMenuElement.uncached { [weak self] completion in
        let actions = [
            UIAction(title: "My Dynamic Action 1", image: UIImage(systemName: "hourglass"), state: self?.myState1 == true ? .on : .off, handler: { (action) in
                // Do something
            }),
            UIAction(title: "My Dynamic Action 2", image: UIImage(systemName: "star"), state: self?.myState2 == true ? .on : .off, handler: { (action) in
                // Do something else
            })
        ] 
        completion(actions)
    }
])
```

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uideferredmenuelement/3857602-elementwithuncachedprovider

Comment: @OmarNShamali Well that's not really true

Comment: Although I didn't paste this exact block, this example provided exactly what I needed. I preferred to create my actions separately then add them as an array to the completion call.  But that's just a style difference.  Anyhow, it worked great.  I now have a checkmark that jumps between my menu items as user chooses one then activates the menu again.  Thanks @Ely!

Comment: Any idea how to do this when the menu needs to stay presented, with actions that have the attribute `UIMenuElement.Attributes.keepsMenuPresented`?

Answer (score 4):

Do not attempt to change the menu while it is showing. Respond to the choice by changing your *data*. At the same time, the menu vanishes, because the user has chosen an action. But now you use that data to construct the menu the *next* time the user displays the menu.

Comment: Example, very similar to what you're trying to do, in case 5 here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/66e806a9e05e7886cff64d4bd1b889104bae49fe/bk2ch12p595NewButtons/NewButtons/ViewController.swift

Comment: `UIBarButtonItem` seems only trigger the menu generation function once

Comment: Sounds like using UIButton can be a work around, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62970548/how-to-modify-uimenu-for-uibarbuttonitem-and-uibutton